# Number of rational solutions to multivariate polynomial

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, rational-numbers

Suppose that I have a quadratic polynomial $p(x,y)$ over the reals with two variables.

> How many rational solutions can $p(x,y)$ have?

Can this be any natural number, or if it is large enough, then it will be infinite?

I know that [deciding whether a solution exists or not can be difficult](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181699/roots-of-rational-equation-with-multiple-variables), I'm only interested in the cardinality.

Comment: $0,1,2,3,4$ and $5 \implies \infty$.

Comment: If that was supposed to be an answer, I have no clue what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: It means the number of of rational points is either $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ or $\infty$. If a "real" quadratic polynomial has at least $5$ rational roots, then it has infinitely many.

Comment: Oh, I see! If you add a link/reference and convert your comment into an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any real quadratic polynomial
$$p(x,y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey + f \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$$
where $a,b,c$ not all zero. Let

- $\mathcal{C} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : p(x,y) = 0 \}$ be its zero set,
- $\mathcal{C}_r = \mathcal{C} \cap \mathbb{Q}^2$ and $N = |\mathcal{C}_r |$
  be its number of rational solutions.

In general, $N$ can be $0,1,2,3,4$ or $\infty$.

In the special case that $p(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ and represents a non-degenerate conic, then $N = 0$ or $\infty$.

---

Geometrically, $\mathcal{C}$ has several possible forms:

1. $\mathcal{C} = \emptyset \implies N = 0.\quad$ (eg. $x^2+y^2+1 = 0$)

   Since $p(x,y)$ has no real solutions, it has no rational solutions.
2. $\mathcal{C}$ is a single point $\implies N = 0$ or $1$.

   - $N = 0\quad$ eg. $(x-\pi)^2 + y^2 = 0$.
   - $N = 1\quad$ eg. $x^2 + y^2 = 0$.
3. $\mathcal{C}$ is a single line $\implies N = 0, 1$ or $\infty$

   - $N = 0\quad$ eg. $(y-\pi)^2 = 0$.
   - $N = 1\quad$ eg. $(y - \pi x)^2 = 0$.
   - $N > 1 \implies N = \infty.$

     Let's say we have found two rational solutions $u,v$ for $p(x,y) = 0$. Since $\lambda u + (1-\lambda) v \in \mathcal{C}_r$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}$, $p(x,y)$ has infinitely many rational solutions.
4. $\mathcal{C}$ is a pair of lines $\implies N = 0, 1, 2$ or $\infty$.

   - $N = 0\quad$ eg. $(y-\pi)(y - \sqrt{2}) = 0$
   - $N = 1\quad$ eg. $(y - \pi x)(y - \pi x - \sqrt{2}) = 0$.
   - $N = 2\quad$ eg. $(y - \pi x)(y - \pi x - 1) = 0$.
   - $N > 2\implies N = \infty$.

     If $p(x,y)$ has more than two rational solutions, at least two of them lie on same line. We can repeat argument of the single line case to deduce $p(x,y)$ has infinitely many rational solutions.
5. $\mathcal{C}$ is non-degenerate (ie. is a parabola/ellipse/hyperbola) $\implies N = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ or $\infty$.

   - $N = 0,\quad$ eg. $x^2+y^2 - 3 = 0$.
   - $N = 1,\quad$ eg. $x^2+y^2 - \pi x = 0$.
   - $N = 2,\quad$ eg. $(x^2+y^2-1) + \pi x^2 = 0$.
   - $N = 3,\quad$ eg. $(x^2 +y^2 - 2x) + \pi(x^2-y^2) = 0$.
   - $N = 4,\quad$ eg. $(x^2+y^2-2) + \pi(x^2-y^2) = 0$.
   - When $N > 4$, let $u_i = (x_i,y_i), i = 1,\ldots, 5$ be five rational solutions of $p(x,y)$. Since the conic is non-degenerate, $\mathcal{C}$ is the zero set of
     another quadratic polynomial with rational coefficients:
     $$q(x,y) \stackrel{def}{=}\left|\begin{matrix}
     x^2 & xy & y^2 & x & y & 1\\
     x_1^2 & x_1y_1 & y_1^2 & x_1 & y_1 & 1\\
     x_2^2 & x_2y_2 & y_2^2 & x_2 & y_2 & 1\\
     x_3^2 & x_3y_3 & y_3^2 & x_3 & y_3 & 1\\
     x_4^2 & x_4y_4 & y_4^2 & x_4 & y_4 & 1\\
     x_5^2 & x_5y_5 & y_5^2 & x_5 & y_5 & 1\end{matrix}\right| \in \mathbb{Q}(x,y)$$
     and there is a $\lambda \ne 0$ such that $p(x,y) = \lambda q(x,y)$.

     Consider the collection of lines passing through $u_1$ with rational slope. With at most one exception (the line coincides with the tangent line of $\mathcal{C}$ at $u_1$), such a line will intersect $\mathcal{C}$ at another point $u' =(x',y')$. Since $p(x',y') = 0 \implies q(x',y') = 0$ and coefficients of $q(x,y)$ are rational, one can use this to deduce $u' \in \mathcal{C}_r$. Since there are infinitely many such lines, $q(x,y) = 0$ and hence $p(x,y) = 0$ has infinitely many rational solutions.

     In the special case $p(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ and represents a non-degenerate conic, the same argument tell us when $p(x,y) = 0$ has a rational solution, it will have infinitely many rational solutions.

Comment: Amazing, five stars!