# How can I "solve" or simplify quadratics of two variables?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots

Given a multivariate polynomial equation like $$xy - bx - ay - ab = 0$$
how do I simplify it, make sense of it, or characterize it?

My attempts so far are below.

---

### Attempt 1

Viewing $x,y$ as variables and $a,b$ as constants, it's obviously of degree 2.  Thus, I won't be able to find any linear solutions in $x$ or $y$.  But I should be able to somehow make *some* sense of it, more than in the current form.

One approach I've tried is finding roots.  As a quadratic, it should be expressable as a product of monomials.  I've looked up on this site and elsewhere, and there seems to be no standard method to do that for multivariate polynomials, but we can treat $x,y$ individually (viewing the other as a constant), giving something like $$x = \frac {a(y-b)}{y-b} \\ = a$$ for $y \neq b$.  But this same argument also gives $y = b$ (!), violating our condition.

A form like $$(x-p)(x-r)(y-q)(y-s) = 0$$ would be ideal.  The above suggests it would simply be $$(x - a)(y - b) = 0$$ which seems to meet the conditions: $[x = a \land y \neq b] \lor [x \neq a \land y = b]$.

Multiplying out, we get $$(x - a)(y - b) = xy - bx - ay + ab$$ and so we've (in some ways) solved the problem.

Still remaining question: What is the locus of $x,y$ that meet that equation?

---

The above seems to have found a simplification, but through a confused and roundabout path (and still incomplete).  Is there a more direct or disciplined approach? Or a way to generalize this? When I see a polynomial in one variable, I immediately know what to do (for some definition of *do*).  What about multivariate?

How can I "solve" these types of equations?  I request that answers don't just solve this question, but show me the method (or point me to a good reference).  Which courses is this normally covered in?

(Note: I've searched math.SE and other sites and found posts like [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28641/roots-of-a-polynomial-in-several-variables), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316752/division-algorithm-for-multivariate-polynomials), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247421/polynomial-remainder-theorem-for-bivariate-polynomials), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181699/roots-of-rational-equation-with-multiple-variables) none of which helped me.)

---

### Attempt 2

As pointed out in the comments, there's an error in the above.  Rather, it should be:
$$
x = a \frac {y+b}{y-b}, \quad y \neq b \\
y = b \frac {x+a}{x-a}, \quad x \neq a
$$ so, if I simplified correctly, $$
x = a \left ( \frac {1 + \frac{x+a}{x-a}} {-1 + \frac{x+a}{x-a}} \right )
$$
which leaves me just as confused! What next?

---

### Update

Let's start a fresh:

$$xy−bx−ay−ab=0$$

Trying to isolate and solve for $x$ or $y$ is a mess, as the above shows.  Lesson: *We can't always solve for $x$!*  Instead, we can notice that:

1. This is a second degree polynomial in two variables
2. and therefore either a conic or degenerate conic
3. which are often best characterized not by $x=...$ but by $(\frac x p - h)^2...$ or something similar.

How do we do that? Let's try to factor our polynomial (or at least the higher degree terms of it) using an analog of completing the square: To get an $xy$ term, our solution will need to look like $$(x - p)(y - q) = r.$$  Then we must have $q =b$, because, when multiplied out, the only coefficient for $x^1$ is $q$.  Likewise, $p = a$, giving $$(x-a)(y-b) = r.$$

Finally, since $$(x-a)(y-b) = xy -bx -ay + ab$$ then $r = 2ab$, giving $$(x-a)(y-b) = 2ab.$$  From knowledge of conics, this is a hyperbola with center $(a, b)$ and "scale factor" (I don't know the proper term) $2ab$.  QED.

Comment: The basic technique here seems to be exactly what's used throughout multivariate mathematics: Analyze each variable _individually_, treating the others as constants.  This makes it clear that the locus is **two perpendicular lines**!

Comment: you have locus $xy - bx - ay - ab = 0$  
and calculation: $(x - a)(y - b) = xy - bx - ay + ab$ .   Look carefully at the $\pm $  signs. Also, please write out the $x,y$   version I recommended on your previous question.

Comment: The other thing useful for anyone is to draw graphs, and get good at sketching graphs by hand. For this problem: compare, what is  the locus of $xy=0$   but then what is the locus of $xy=1?$

Comment: @WillJagy From $(x-a)(y-b)=0$, I conclude that either $x = a$ or $y = b$.  These both fulfill the original equation.  Can you explain what direction beyond that you're pointing me in? Re your individual points: 1. I've checked the $\pm$ signs and they seem correct.  Nor do they seem to show any pattern of interest 2. I'm not sure change you recommend: I've used scalars here, no vectors, and there's no $x^2$ to complete the square with 3. $xy = k$ is a hyperbola, but it's not clear how that helps me here (degenerate hyperbola is two intersecting lines?). Can you please elaborate?

Comment: $xy-bx-ay - ab = (x-a)(y-b)  - 2ab$  so the product is not zero

Comment: Don't  "solve" for anything here....  Part 1:   what is the locus $xy=1?$   Part 1 and a half: what is the locus $(x-a)(y-b) = 1?$    Part 2:  what is the locus $(x-a)(y-b)  = 2ab?$

Comment: Let me put in an advertisement for pure translations. If I first give you $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ you tell me it is a circle of radius $5$  around $(0,0)$   If I then, as in the other problem, give you $(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2 = 25,$  you tell mi it is a circle of radius $5$ around center $(3,4)$   Similar:  first I give you $xy=1.$  This is a hyperbola, one arc in the first quadrant and one in the third. It does have a "center,"  it is symmetric (in more than one way)  around the origin. Next:  what is the locus $(x-3)(y-4)= 1?$ Around what point is it symmetric?

Comment: @WillJagy Can you take a look at the update? In particular, did I extract the general method properly: If you can't solve for $x$, factor the polynomial, or at least some of it, using a method similar to completing the square.

Comment: well, you are right that we are discussing conic sections  as long as thre are constants, take capital letters $A,B,C,D,E,F$ and the locus of this set of $x,y$  points:  $Ax^2 + Bxy +Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F=0$     When $B=0$  you can find this as a translation by completing squares, $A(x-a)^2 + C(y-b)^2 = W$   for some new constant $W.$  Instead, if $B$  is nonzero but $A=C=0$  you have a translated hyperbola, as in the current problem. If all of $A,B,C \neq 0$  we also need rotations. Off to get groceries

Comment: anyway, if you know enough about the locus of $g(x,y) = C,$   then the locus of $g(x-a,y-b)= C $ is just the original translated

Comment: *there seems to be no standard method to do that for multivariate polynomials* --- True, but the school algebra method [factoring by grouping](https://www.google.com/search?q=factoring+by+grouping) is the obvious method to try in this case. See also the answers and comments to [How to simpify this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/716045/13130)